# USB Debugging greyed out on Samsung Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

My Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (SM-T210) running Android 4.4.2 (kitkat) has suddenly greyed out the USB Debugging option in settings. I've yet to find a fix on the internet, I've tried:

- Device Restart
- Cable plugged/unplugged
- Tapping Build Number (gives 'No need, developer mode has already been enabled')
- Selecting both MTP and PTP from USB options
- App 'MyKnox' is not installed

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

D'oh. There's a switch at the top you need to toggle.